# How can I access a raspi-config submenus directly?

Tags: raspbian-buster, raspi-config, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I am working on a script that needs to access raspi-config at "Interface Options > I2C" directly.
Is there a way to do this at the command line ?

Thanks

Comment: maybe use raspi-config in non-interactive mode? https://github.com/raspberrypi-ui/rc_gui/blob/master/src/rc_gui.c#L81

Comment: Hmm, `grep nonint $(which raspi-config)` does point the way to such functionality, so probably no hackyness required, which brings it back on-topic I think.  All apologies.

Comment: @goldilocks the Pi GUI version of config utility (which uses the nonint bits) is mostly a frontend for raspi-config

Comment: I realize that; those defines are for invocating `raspi-config`.  Some of them have `[s]printf` style substitutions in them (eg `%d`) which are placeholders for an additional argument to the invocation.  The other ones aren't concatenated (probably -- I only checked a few) so you should be able to use them verbatim (eg. `raspi-config nonint do_boot_behaviour B1`).  Most of the ones that don't have dynamic args are for getting current settings tho.  So for case in point here you'd have to look at `raspi-config` to find out what the valid args are for `raspi-config nonint do_i2c %d` <- integer.

Comment: ...You don't have to understand C or read through the GUI source, this will all be plainly laid out in `raspi-config` if you follow the script parameters starting with `nonint`, etc.  They of course have not bothered documenting this AFAICT: https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config @FedeKrum If this all isn't clear to you leave a comment and I could come up with an answer; otherwise please add one yourself when you get the details sorted.